# GridView scroll with images is not scrolling smooth

Tags: android

Hello as i am new in Android development and dont know much about the scroll view and now i am facing a problem about the scrolling of gridView, My grid view has 20 images in it and when i attempt to scroll it down to see the images it doesn't scroll properly it slows down and sometimes it used to say app has stop responding and crashed down. can any one help me out to make the scroll smooth and solve this problem.
here is my code for the "ImageAdapter"

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Context mContext;

    private int[] mThumbsIda={
            R.drawable.sample_1,
            R.drawable.sample_2,
            R.drawable.sample_3,
            R.drawable.sample_4,
            R.drawable.sample_5,
            R.drawable.sample_6,
            R.drawable.sample_7,
            R.drawable.sample_8,
            R.drawable.sample_9,
            R.drawable.sample_10,
            R.drawable.sample_11,
            R.drawable.sample_12,
            R.drawable.sample_13,
            R.drawable.sample_14,
            R.drawable.sample_15,
            R.drawable.sample_16,
            R.drawable.sample_17,
            R.drawable.sample_18,
            R.drawable.sample_19,
            R.drawable.sample_20,
            R.drawable.sample_21,
            R.drawable.sample_22,
            R.drawable.sample_23
    };

    public ImageAdapter(Context c){
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount(){
        return mThumbsIda.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {

            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,385));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);

        }
        else{
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbsIda[position]);
        return imageView;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use UIL, Glide or Picasso for load images

Comment: May be images are high resolution, due to that high resolution gridview getting lag, for smooth scroll use Image Loader library.

Comment: i dont know how to use image loader library. can you help me out @Mohan or is ther any other way to over come this issue ?

Comment: @SafiUllahShahid - There are many image libraries are available, for example Glide is one of the best library, using those libraries our application will be no lag, library will maintain cache, if the image loading first time then save image into cache memory, if same image want to load again then library will pick from the cache, please follow the below tutorial, you can load images from drawable folder / from server as well, https://www.androidhive.info/2016/04/android-glide-image-library-building-image-gallery-app/, Hope this will help you